# Shouldn't the "impossible" badges be removed?

Tags: discussion, bounty, badges, meta

You can't set bounties on meta sites

So why are there still those 4 bounty related badges!?

P.S. I definitely wasn't going to waste atleast 100 reputation points just to get atleast two badges that no one has. What a shame would that be

Comment: I think it is just that no one found it relevant enough to remove them. There are a few other badges that are and were impossible to gain (on some sites). Some of them are marked as such but maybe not all.

Comment: It seems like this might be better asked on the main meta site, [meta.se].

Comment: While @XanderHenderson has a point it could be relevant there to insist on the fact that it is not possible on *per site* metas; on the main one, and only there, it is possible.

Comment: I didn't even know about that site. EDIT:and this question has already been asked Atleast twice there.

Comment: See [Per-site metas: Inform of impossible badges; And change incorrect “can earn rep” statement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243435/295232) on Meta Stack Exchange.